# How do I call a method of an object stored in a vector containing various objects?

Tags: java, oop, vector

I have a Vector list of objects from different classes, in which I need to invoke a method specific to a class. Here's an example

here the class of the object,

```
public class VariableElement extends FormulaElement{

  private double varValue;

  public void setVariableValue(double varValue) {
      this.varValue = varValue;
  }
}
```

Here's where I want to call the method, which is another method inside the FormulaElement class

```
public void setVariableValue(double value){

  for(Object o:tokenVector){
     if(o instanceof VariableElement){
            o.setVariableValue(value);//throws error symbol not found
     } 
  }    
}
```

this is basically what I want to do but it gives an error, how do I fix this issue, is it possible at all? thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is no `setVariableValue()` method on `Object`.  You need to cast `o` before you can invoke that method on it.

Answer (score 1):

Cast your Object to a VariableElement first.

```
public void setVariableValue(double value){
  for(Object o:tokenVector){
     if(o instanceof VariableElement){
        VariableElement ve = (VariableElement)o;
        ve.setVariableValue(value);
     } 
  }    
}
```

Comment: What would happen if there are more than one VariableElement Objects in the vector? will the new value overwrite the previous one?

Comment: @Laventio_19 *All* VariableElements in the list will have their variable values set to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to case `o` to a `VariableElement`. Just make the following change

```
((VariableElement)o).setVariableValue(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have different objects then you should probably define an `interface` to specify the  method you want them to call.  If the method is the same for all objects, then you can just cast that object to the `interface type` and call the method.

```java
    List<Object> objects = List.of(new Lion(), new Gazelle());

    for (Object o : objects) {
       ((SupperTime) o).feedMe();
    }



    interface SupperTime {
       public void feedMe();
    }

    class Lion implements SupperTime {
       public void feedMe() {
          System.out.println("I want a gazelle");
       }
    }

    class Gazelle implements SupperTime {
       public void feedMe() {
          System.out.println("I want some veggies");
       }
    }
```